# Can Email to Salesforce leverage Shared Activities?

Tags: email, activities

I noticed that I can leverage Shared Activities on outbound emails from Salesforce, but it seems like Email to Salesforce doesn't seem to support it. Was curious if anyone had a good workaround on implementing it -- would a trigger capture the entire batch of users in the "TO" field and let you write code to compact 3 emails into one activity? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salesforce delivered this natively back in the Summer 13 Release.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000hqc7AAA

Prior to that, we wrote a trigger on Task to determine if it was an email, and if so manually parse through the To/From fields and associating with Contacts with matching emails in the system.